# consulta con varios estados mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo una duda con una consulta de mysql.

lo que necesito obtener son los `nombres` que tengan solo el `estado` = `1`. Como se puede ver en la tabla, el `nombre` "pepe" tiene estado "1 y 0", hay alguna forma de excluirlo?

```
    tabla personas

    id |estado|nombre
     1 |  1   |pepe
     2 |  0   |pepe
     3 |  1   |juan
     4 |  1   |diego
     5 |  0   |alex
```

lo que tengo es esto

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    personas 
WHERE 
    estado in (SELECT 
                  DISTINCT estado 
               FROM 
                  personas 
               WHERE estado = 1)
```

pero me muestra todos los que tienen estado 1.. y no logro excluir a los que tienen 0 y 1,espero se entienda, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM personas p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM personas
                 WHERE estado <> 1
                 AND nombre = p.nombre);
```

Answer (score 4):

O puedes usar `NOT IN`:

```
select *
from personas
where nombre not in
(
  select nombre from personas
  where estado = 0
)
```

**SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ab6ad/1**

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes una respuesta válida, te voy a poner una alternativa que es algo diferente pero te puede valer también:

```
SELECT   id, (MIN(estado) && 1) AS estado, nombre
FROM     personas
GROUP BY nombre
HAVING   estado = 1;
```

La idea es que siempre nos vamos a quedar con el estado de menor valor que tenga una persona, para sólo quedarnos con los registros cuyo resultado sea 1 al hacer un Y lógico con 1:

```
Y | 0 | 1
--+---+--
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
```

Esta consulta se basa en la idea de que `estado` sólo va a tener los valores 1 ó 0 (o que va a tener diferentes valores pero sólo queremos excluir los que tengan un 0). Entonces, la consulta sólo devolverá los registros que o bien tengan 1, o que si tienen más de un estado, ninguno de ellos es 0.

Lo puedes ver funcionando (comparado con las otras respuestas) en este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76947/7).